# Pygame 3.3 Not updating screen correctly leading to freeze

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Within my program I have a Popup object that upon being created, draws a message to the screen, pauses, and then removes it. This works absolutely fine most of the time, including when messages are chained together one after the other. However, if at any point the game window comes out of focus for any reason (it is minimized or you click on another window), then after one or two chained popups, the screen will freeze and not show any subsequent ones, becoming responsive again after the last popup would have disappeared. This appears to occur just before the popup disappears, as the one it gets stuck on remains visible for the duration of the freeze.

I have no idea if this is a problem with Python or Pygame, but I'm hoping it's something I've done so it can be fixed. Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

```
class Popup():

def __init__(self,surface,font,colour,thickness,text,textcolour,duration,align="center",x=None,y=None): #Position can be specified, but will default to centre of screen.
    self.surface = surface
    self.font = font
    self.colour = colour
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.thickness = thickness
    self.text = text
    self.textcolour = textcolour
    self.duration = duration
    self.align = align

    self.appear()
    sleep(self.duration) #I want to thread this if I can. For now, it pauses the entire program, so don't use long durations!
    self.disappear()

def appear(self):
    screenBorder = pygame.Rect(0,0,self.surface.get_width()-10,50) #Limits text width to slightly smaller than screen.
    message = multiLineText(None,self.font,self.text,self.textcolour,screenBorder,self.align)

    POPUPSURF = pygame.Surface((message.get_width()+(self.thickness*2),message.get_height()+(self.thickness*2))).convert_alpha() #New surface size of message plus border.
    POPUPSURF.fill(self.colour)
    POPUPSURF.blit(message,(self.thickness,self.thickness)) #Add the text.

    if self.thickness > 0:
        alphas = []
        increment = int(255/self.thickness)
        for i in range(self.thickness):
            alphas.append(increment*(i+1))

        for alpha in alphas:
            num = alphas.index(alpha)
            thisL = POPUPSURF.get_width() - (2*num)
            thisH = POPUPSURF.get_height() - (2*num)

            R,G,B = self.colour
            pygame.draw.rect(POPUPSURF,(R,G,B,alpha),(num,num,thisL,thisH),1) #Draw border.

    if self.x == None:
        self.x = (self.surface.get_width()/2) - (POPUPSURF.get_width()/2)
    if self.y == None:
        self.y = (self.surface.get_height()/2) - (POPUPSURF.get_height()/2)

    self.BACKUPSURF = pygame.Surface((POPUPSURF.get_width(),POPUPSURF.get_height()))
    self.BACKUPSURF.blit(self.surface,(0,0),(self.x,self.y,POPUPSURF.get_width(),POPUPSURF.get_height())) #Takes a copy of what it looks like without popup. This can be restored in disappear().

    self.surface.blit(POPUPSURF,(self.x,self.y))
    pygame.display.update()

def disappear(self):
    self.surface.blit(self.BACKUPSURF,(self.x,self.y))
    pygame.display.update()
    sleep(0.1)
```

Example of usage:

```
expGainPopup = Popup(DISPLAYSURF,font,DARKRED,10,"You have gained %d EXP!" %gain,WHITE,DURATION) #Inform of gain.

if player["Level"] < 15: #If not max level (would cause out-of-bounds error on array)
    progressPopup = Popup(DISPLAYSURF,font,DARKRED,10,"You now have %d EXP out of %d to level up." %(player["EXP"], levels[player["Level"]]),WHITE,DURATION) #Inform of progress.
```

If anyone wants to test the code, they will also need the MultiLineText function:

```
def multiLineText(background,font,text,colour,boundary=None,align="left",returnNum=False): #NB the boundary ONLY cares about width/length. It will not limit the height of returned surface objects.
if type(boundary) == pygame.Rect: #If a valid boundary is passed
    testSection = ""
    testResult = ""
    for word in findall(r'\S+|\n',text): #Borrowed this from my text compressor program. Splits all words and newlines, as \S+ finds a non-whitespace character and all similar characters following it. \n will match all newlines, treating them as words. | is just the 'or' operator. r makes it a raw string so Python doesn't get confused with all the formatting symbols.
        testSection += " "+word #Remember to add spaces back in!
        if word == "\n":
            testResult += testSection #Skip check and auto-newline if it is a newline
            testSection = ""
        elif font.size(testSection)[0] > boundary.width: #If has exceeded one line length
            testSection = testSection[:-len(word)-1] #Remove the word, -1 also removes the space before the word.
            testResult += testSection+"\n" #Add string with line break to the result.
            testSection = " "+word #Restart testSection with word that did not fit, ready for new line.
    testResult += testSection #Add the last section that never reached the max length to the output so it doesn't get lost.
    lines = testResult.split("\n")
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i] = lines[i][1:] #Removes the first character, an unwanted space.
else: #If just working off existing \n in the text
    lines = text.split("\n")

lengths = []
for line in lines:
    lengths.append(font.size(line)[0])
length = max(lengths) #Length is set to the length of the longest individual line.

totalHeight = 0
for line in lines:
    totalHeight += font.size(line)[1]
TEXTSURF = pygame.Surface((length,totalHeight)).convert_alpha()
if background != None: #Fill the background with colour or transparency.
    TEXTSURF.fill(background)
else:
    TEXTSURF.fill((0,0,0,0))

for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] += str(i) #Add a unique identifier onto every line. This way if two or more lines are the same, index(line) will not return the wrong value, resulting in repeated lines not appearing.

for line in lines:
    dudChars = len(str(lines.index(line))) #The number of characters in the index of this line within lines, and therefore the character length of the unique identifier we want to remove.
    renderedLine = font.render(line[:-dudChars],True,colour) #Render the line without identifier.

    if align == "left":
        xpos = 0
    elif align == "center":
        xpos = (length/2) - (renderedLine.get_width()/2)
    elif align == "right":
        xpos = length - renderedLine.get_width()

    ypos = int((lines.index(line)) * (totalHeight/len(lines))) #Find the appropriate vertical space

    TEXTSURF.blit(renderedLine,(xpos,ypos)) #Add to the multiline surface.

if returnNum == False:
    return TEXTSURF
else:
    return TEXTSURF, len(lines) #Return the number of lines used as well, if it was asked for.
```

Comment: No code -- instant downvote. How are we supposed to know what's causing the problem?

Comment: Please add code relevant to the problem. For reference: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JonathonOgden Code has been added, sorry!

Comment: Answer your own question, and put your solution in there. Leave your original post alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually solved by adding in the `pygame.event.pump` function into key places. This allows pygame to process its internal events such as talking with the OS. Without this, the event queue is paused for too long and the program gets flagged as not responding, the screen freezes, and bad things happen.

Relevant fixed code (only one line different):

```
def disappear(self):
    self.surface.blit(self.BACKUPSURF,(self.x,self.y))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.event.pump() #So the display updates properly, stops it from freezing and making you miss messages. This allows pygame to do some internal events such as talking to the OS. Otherwise, if the event queue has been paused for too long, the OS will treat it as not responding, and bad things happen.
    sleep(0.1)
```